# Slim framework seems not calling function

Tags: php, apache, slim

I am not a php expert. However I am in need of building a simple rest service, mainly with  GET request to be used with a mobile application.

I have read something about Slim Framework, and tried to implement a simple example.

While I am not getting any error, it also seems that the function is not being called.

This is the source:

```
<?php
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->get('/ping', function () {
    echo "Works !!!";
});

$app->run;
```

I didn't do anything on .htaccess so I am calling like this:

```
http://mywebsite/services/service.php/ping
```

index.php is called with status 200 as I can see from logs, but I am getting no output at all.

I tried several servers and getting same results. Obviously I am missing something.

Comment: Why the backslashes before the class name?

Comment: uhm...I just copied the "Hello World" example, there it is called with a backslash.

Comment: @LiamBailey The backslashes are used because Slim is a namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not having used Slim, I'm going to make a guess and say `$app->run` should be `$app->run();`

Comment: well, shame on me ! The problem was really in those missing parenthesis. After so many years working in IT...I am still doing this sort of mistakes. Strange I wasn't getting any error.